# python pyxb - unmarshaling a list of subtypes

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I am using pyxb 1.1.5 ... created binding module for the xsd.
Trying to populate and create xml ...

BaseFooList has a list of BaseFoo

Trying to populate with a sub-type FooOne will raise a validation exception when populating
the sub-type element

```
t = vnet.root(type="GGG")
t.city="C1"
t.name="N1"
t.foos = BaseFooList()
foo1 = FooOne()
foo1.next="sss"
t.foos.item.append(foo1)
print t.toxml()
```

===>
pyxb.exceptions_.StructuralBadDocumentError: Validation is required when no element_use can be found

Thanks,
Ran